# ForeignKey Inline dropdown menu in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a project with the following models

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length = 200, blank=False)
    content = RichTextUploadingField("Content")

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Tag", max_length = 50)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

and the following admin.py

```
class TagInline (admin.StackedInline):
    model = Tag

class RecipePage(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title')
    list_display_links = ('title')
    fields = ('title', 'content')
    list_per_page = 25

    inlines = (TagInline)
```

For each inline, I would like Django's admin to show a list of tag names as a drop-down menu, based on the tags that have already been entered. Of course, users must be able to add a new tag name, as a tag object, if no suitable tag exists already. I can achieve this quite easily **without** inline, but **with** it, I'm not able to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in the **inline** represents one record of the "Tag" table, or object of the  class "Tag".
While entering new entry to this inline means you are actually creating new tags under one "Recipe". The "recipe" column of the "Tag" table will be filled with the primary key of Recipe table.

I don't really understood why you need inline here. If you need multiple tags tagged to one Recipe, then  you can go with ManyToManyFields, In this case you can chose multiple tags in the drop down.(This django admin will take care, you only need to change the type of recipe to ManytoManyField)